# JQuery/CSS: Animate static position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a smooth transition from one form field type to another. If I insert another `<input>` element however, the static position of the next elements aren't animated.

```js
$("#switchlogin").click(function() {
  //Create the label element
  var emaillabel = $("<label>").text("Email").attr("for", "email");
  //Create the input element
  var emailinput = $('<input type="text">').attr({
    id: "email",
    name: "email"
  });

  //Create the label element
  var pwdlabel = $("<label>").text("Repeat Password").attr("for", "password-wh");
  //Create the input element
  var pwdinput = $('<input type="password">').attr({
    id: "password-wh",
    name: "password-wh"
  });

  $("#username-field").after(emaillabel);
  emaillabel.after(emailinput);

  $("#password-field").after(pwdlabel);
  pwdlabel.after(pwdinput);
});
```

```css
input {
  border: solid #e3e3e3 1pt;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 14pt;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn .3s forwards;
}
label {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn .3s forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="login" method="post">
  <div id="username-field">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
  </div>

  <div id="password-field">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
  </div>

  <div id="buttons-field">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <a href="#" id="switchlogin">Register</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fpvctpjs/2/

So what I want is that, when the register link is pressed, the `password-field` moves down smoothly to make place for the new elements.

I tried several things, like adding `margin-top`, `position:absolute` or `position:relative` but somehow I can't get it to work.

Thank you for your help,
marsman

Comment: Personally I think its not a good idea to add inputs to login form to be a register form .. for me I will create 2 separated forms one for login and one for register  and slideUp one and slideDown another .. Again  (for me) its a better way to do that ..

Comment: unrelated to your question, but noteworthy:  Clicking the **Register** button adds the input fields _each time_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your password field isn't animating smoothly because its movement is a result of the other fields being appended.

What would be best is to have the other fields always there, but hidden inside of a div with height:0;—and then when you click on the reset button, animate to the desired height of that div and fade in the child inputs.

Comment: @marsman awesome. would you mind marking this as the answer? cheers.